# Filter records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, filter, limit

I'm trying to limit the results of a SQL Server query.

I've got this query

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    MEMB_INFO
LEFT JOIN Character ON Character.AccountID = MEMB_INFO.memb___id
WHERE   CtlCode <> 8
        AND CtlCode <> 32
ORDER BY Name
```

I want to paginate it.  I've found that using

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Name ) AS rownum
          FROM      Character
        ) AS A
WHERE   A.rownum BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

works, but I've got no idea how to add the `LEFT JOIN` and the `WHERE` to this query.

I'm using SQL Server 2010

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is not your question, but you probably want from 11 to 20, right? To take 10 by 10 records each time.

Comment: There is **NO** SQL Server 2010 version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 - which one are you **really** using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (        
      SELECT  [Character].Name 
             ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Character].Name) AS rownum
      FROM MEMB_INFO LEFT JOIN [Character] 
       ON [Character].AccountID = MEMB_INFO.memb___id 
      AND CtlCode <> 8 AND CtlCode <> 32 
     ) AS A
WHERE A.rownum  BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: I'm getting Null on all the "name" column. Ty

Comment: This is because some MEMB_INFO.memb___id has no pair in [Character].AccountID. So, the query will return NULL for this cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` keywords, just like:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM MEMB_INFO A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Character
    ORDER BY Name
    OFFSET 10 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
) B
ON B.AccountID = A.memb___id
WHERE   CtlCode not in (8,32)
ORDER BY NAME
```

Then to paginate, you just need to take the number of page starting from zero and multiply by the number defined in `OFFSET` (number of pages to jump). The size of page is what is defined in `FETCH`.

Find out more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm using 2010, sorry i forgot to tell you

Comment: Ok. I will let my answer here because maybe someone can use it. Thanks.